# Quick query times out. Msg: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In my c# application the insert query below is executed. This has been running for about 6 months without any issues. However now sometimes the query doesn't run & get the error message below but other times it does work.

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

When I execute the query in SQL it only takes 1 second to execute so am a bit confused. The table contains approx 3,500,000 records so quite small I assume by SQL standards. Generally the insert query uploads approx 20,000 records.

MyTable1 (where the data is getting inserted into) has the 5 columns, no primary key. It does have 4 indices though.

Code

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(myConnection))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblTable1 select '2016-10-10', DatePrice, ISIN, Price, PriceFull from tblTable2 where DatePrice='2016-10-07'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that there is no blocking in your database. You might (in theory at least) have also different query plans in application vs. management studio because of different connection parameters, but that sounds a little bit far fetched in this case.

Comment: I'm curious, does it only sometimes time out and sometimes work?  If so, do you know if the database has been changed to high availability? Try adding "multisubnetfailover=true" to the connection parameters as the database could have been.

Comment: So when running the query in SQL Server it always works. In the application when it tries running the query the success rate is about 50%. Not sure what has changed. I will ask our IT team if any changes have been made to the database without informing us

Comment: @JamesZ i used exec sp_who & exec sp_who2 to check for any blocking & there was none

Comment: Check the stack trace to see where it gets stucked.  I have a feeling that it has problem of establishing the connection.

Comment: @JasonChing the stack trace tells me the error occurs at the line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); in my code above